# Autocomplete Google maps API returns NULL

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, android-studio-2.0

I am a newbie to android and google maps. Basically, I want to provide a search bar besided my mapview to users. The search bar should enable user to search for restaurants. 
I tried using the google autocomplete API . However, when I type one character to it, it returns null .

The code for my layout xml is :

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"/>
```

And I am simply loading this xml from my fragment class. 
Do I need to do anything in my fragment class to make this work?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah, you need some java logic, even the layout piece of code seems incomplete, I'd put there an AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: Hi @slanecek , Can you please provide some tutorial link ? That will be very much helpful

Comment: You can get some inspiration from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602027/get-other-values-according-to-the-item-selected-in-autocompletetextview

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorials on the internet that can help you with your problem. From the Google documentation itself, they have a guideline on what autocomplete can do plus some sample code. The [autocomplete service](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) in the Google Places API for Android returns place predictions in response to user search queries. As the user types, the autocomplete service returns suggestions for places such as businesses, addresses and points of interest.

You can add autocomplete to your app in the following ways:

- Add an [autocomplete widget](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#add_an_autocomplete_widget) to save development time and ensure a consistent user experience.
- Get [place predictions programmatically](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically) to create a customized user experience.

Just check the documentation above for more information.

For the different tutorials, you can follow either of these:

- [Android – AutoCompleteTextView with Google Places Autocomplete API](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/)
- [Google Place API Autocomplete Service in Android Application](http://codetheory.in/google-place-api-autocomplete-service-in-android-application/)
- [Android Google Places Autocomplete API Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-autocomplete-api-example/)

Answer (score 0):

[image: error_message_screen_shot]

I went to [postman](https://web.postman.co/home) and paste the query to see what result do I get. Apparently, I didn't enable Billing in Google Cloud Platform.

Possible Solution:

1. Try enabling Billing in your Google Cloud Platform by filling up your debit/credit card info to start free trial.
2. Check if you enabled "Places API" in your Google Cloud Platform